# Gradle adds external libraries from wrong directory

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I am using the `fileTree` Gradle task to import some external libraries

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'C:\\Intellij\\cast\\grails-app\\libs', include: '*.jar')
```

The issue is that when I build my Gradle project it actually pulls JAR files from a different directory `C:\\Intellij\\cis\\grails-app\\libs`

If I put that same exact `fileTree` task in any other project it will properly pull JAR files from the `CAST` directory but in the actual `CAST`project it pulls from `CIS`.  I have done a complete text search of the entire `CAST`project and there are no references to the `CIS`project so I have no idea why its doing this.  If I modify the contents of the `CIS`lib folder then those changes are reflected when I refresh my `CAST`project.

What do I need to do to make sure that when I specify that I want to pull libraries from the `CAST` directory that it actually does instead of pulling from somewhere else?

Comment: can you do `--refresh-dependencies` to see it works?

Comment: @chenrui Doing that removes the CIS jars but the CAST jars are not added, as if it can't find the directory.  It does exist though because I can reference the CAST directory from another project and using the `--refresh-dependencies` works as expected

Comment: That sounds super weird, can you add your `settings.gradle` as well as your folder tree relationships?